# Shift values in array [C#]

Tags: c#

I would like to shift values in an array to the corners.

This is my 2-dimensional array:

```
4, 8, 0, 2
0, 6, 1, 9
7, 0, 5, 3
```

I want to shift all 0 values to the corners so it looks like:

```
0, 4, 8, 0
2, 6, 1, 9
0, 7, 5, 3

0, 4, 8, 0
2, 6, 1, 9
7, 5, 3, 0

0, 4, 8, 2
6, 1, 9, 7
0, 5, 3, 0

4, 8, 2, 0
6, 1, 9, 7
0, 5, 3, 0
```

There is an easy way to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to define the rules for shifting. I see a single input array and 4 outputs? Why 4 outputs? How do you know which corners to shift the 0 values to?

Comment: I wanna make an output of all possible options (for all corners)

Comment: What if there are more than 4 zeroes in the array? There are only 4 corners in a square.

Comment: In this case, you can throw an exception...

Comment: The easiest way is to post your question on stackoverflow and hope someone else writes the code for you without attempting anything yourself. But sarcasm aside, you will need to make an attempt and post back here with what you tried and what isn't working in order to get a proper response.

Comment: No there is not an easy way to manipulate 2D arrays in C#. Other languages like MatLab have methods to manipulate arrays but C# does not. You basically need to copy the data to a new array, and write the logic to decide where the data goes,